# Discretize matrix in R according to classification rule

Tags: r, matrix

My matrix consists of numbers:

```
set.seed(2016)
A <- matrix(rnorm(4,250,50), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

I want to discretize them into 3 classes: `lmh <- c("low", "moderate", "high")`

```
low: <30
medium: 30 - 300
high >300
```

Is this possible without converting the matrix into a `data.frame` and without using a loop?

This seems like a very easy task but I could not find anything.

Comment: @9Jan i need both

Comment: See `?cut`. `cut(A, breaks = c(-Inf, 30, 300, Inf), labels = c("low", "moderate", "high"))`. Assign the result to `A[] <- as.character(cut(...))` to keep the dimensions and produce a `character` matrix. Alternately `result = matrix(as.character(cut(...), nrow = nrow(A))` if you don't want to overwrite `A`.

Comment: the output should be a matrix

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(A < 30   ~ 'low'
        , A <= 300 ~ 'medium'
        , T        ~ 'high') %>% 
  `dim<-`(dim(A))
```

Or

```
A %>% 
  cut(breaks = c(-Inf, 30, 300, Inf), labels = c("low", "med", "high")) %>% 
  `dim<-`(dim(A))
```